# Why is node in chrome audit with lighthouse this slow?

Tags: node.js, angular, performance, express, lighthouse

I just created a single page js as below:

```
// Load HTTP module
var http = require("http");

// Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

   // Set the response HTTP header with HTTP status and Content type
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(57777);

// Print URL for accessing server
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:57777/');
```

So it hosts on localhost:57777. And here are the audit result for it.

[image: Image showing audit]

I started learning express so as to improve my Angular SSR performance but here I see that a blank project with text response is so bad at performance then how can I expect my angular app to be better. Can I fix the performance lagging ?

*Or should I shift to laravel or other PHP framework for performance as I've spent a lot of time angular and still the app isn't that great.*

Here is the report of my Angular Universal project which makes it impossible to keep it deployed.

[image: Angular stats]

**Is there a way to improve the above I'm following this** [Universal Starter's configuration](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

I've followed these blogs as well but to no help:

1. [A medium blog](https://medium.com/paramsingh-66174/catalysing-your-angular-4-app-performance-9211979075f6)
2. [Almost completely implemented this checklist](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist)

Comment: What operating system are you running this on?  Keep in mine that the timing results you are able to get will depend on the accuracy of the operating systems timing resolution, on Windows this is terrible, results cannot be accurately calculated for Windows with a timing resolution of approx. 50ms.

Comment: Yes I'm using windows 8.1 and Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable). But the stats are too bad for any website even with minor flaw in calculations this is too bad.

Comment: I would suggest looking into timer resolution for Windows. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757633(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The link was for information only, if you call any routine to obtain the system time you will find that accuracy is way off, try calling the same routine twice one call immediately followed by another then measure the difference between the two values you will see what I mean.  Use a routing that returns microseconds then see how many microseconds has elapsed between two calls.

Comment: Here's what I think you're saying 
```
console.log(new Date().getTime());
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(new Date().getTime());
},1000)
1534920274189
1534920275192
```

Comment: Now modify it to show the difference between the two values, you should see that although your timer that is performing this function is 1000 ms, the difference between iterations is quite different.  getTime() returns the EPOCH time in milliseconds since 1970.  On Linux or QNX(real time OS) the accuracy of a millisecond timer is accurate to one millisecond resolution.

Comment: Yes but I'm using google tool to audit and google use that for Website performance as well so that shouldn't be a cause though

Comment: What does the tool actually measure? The time to "first contentfull paint" for your hello world app was about 0.5 s; What takes then 15 s for "time to interactive" for a site that does not have any interaction?

Comment: Don't know about that but it's inbuild audit tool in chrome. You can go to inspect(Dev Tool) in this window then go to audit tab almost last there you'll get the result for your app.@Henry

Comment: Thank you @Henry your comment forced me to dig deeper and I found that I was able find out the cause for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Henry's comment I was forced to dig deeper and I found the devil behind this low performance.
[image: The devil]

When I was running the audit and I found that all the extensions that I have installed on my browser are also taken into account.

**So the solution is to: Run audit in an incognito window.**
Now I'll move ahead to optimize my angular.